# Why do values in nested list not update?

Tags: python, csv

I have a python function (resultsUpdate), which updates a nested list named resultsTable, containing values taken from a CSV file by changing the values contained in three of its columns with the values contained in three other lists, which the function takes as input.

```
def resultsUpdate(self, resultsTable, listPrefInd_a, listPrefInd_b, listPerfInd):
    count = 0           
    for row in resultsTable:
        while(count<len(resultsTable)-1):
            print(count)
            row[12] = listPrefInd_a[count]
            row[13] = listPrefInd_b[count]
            row[14] = listPerfInd[count]
            print(row[12])                #debugging print
            count+=1
            print(resultsTable[count])
```

When I check if the values have updated with the print statement, they seem to have updated), however when I print the whole resultsTable the three columns are not updated. Any ideas why?

Example output

```
0
0.4230769230769231
['1', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '15', '7', '4', 'BA', '11', '6', '13', '0', '0', '0']
1
-0.3793103448275862
['2', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '6', '17', 'BA', '4', '11', '15', '0', '0', '0']
2
-0.03125
['3', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '9', '13', '10', 'AM', '8', '14', '11', '0', '0', '0']
3
-0.0625
['4', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '10', '10', '12', 'BA', '7', '9', '14', '0', '0', '0']
4
-0.0625
['5', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '10', '10', '12', 'AM', '10', '7', '13', '0', '0', '0']
5
-0.72
['6', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '1', '5', '19', 'BA', '7', '9', '13', '0', '0', '0']
```

resultsTable:

```
[['nummer', 'datum', 'larvae', 'zeit', 'gruppe1', 'cs_a', 'med_a', 'neut_a', 'gruppe2', 'cs_b', 'med_b', 'neut_b', 'prefInd_a', 'prefInd_b', 'perfInd'], ['1', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '15', '7', '4', 'BA', '11', '6', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '6', '17', 'BA', '4', '11', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['3', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '9', '13', '10', 'AM', '8', '14', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['4', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '10', '10', '12', 'BA', '7', '9', '14', '0', '0', '0'], ['5', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '10', '10', '12', 'AM', '10', '7', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['6', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '1', '5', '19', 'BA', '7', '9', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['7', '23.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '2', '1', '25', 'AM', '14', '3', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['8', '23.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '10', '8', 'BA', '2', '7', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['9', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'BA', '8', '9', '7', 'AM', '6', '8', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['10', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'AM', '5', '8', '16', 'BA', '10', '5', '16', '0', '0', '0'], ['11', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'BA', '9', '11', '6', 'AM', '7', '12', '16', '0', '0', '0'], ['12', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'AM', '14', '7', '12', 'BA', '8', '5', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['13', '25.01', '17.01', '13.23', 'BA', '4', '9', '17', 'AM', '2', '3', '25', '0', '0', '0'], ['14', '25.01', '17.01', '13.46', 'AM', '8', '11', '15', 'BA', '6', '5', '19', '0', '0', '0'], ['15', '25.01', '18.01', '14.49', 'BA', '6', '9', '12', 'AM', '6', '5', '17', '0', '0', '0'], ['16', '25.01', '18.01', '15.24', 'AM', '2', '7', '21', 'BA', '3', '7', '20', '0', '0', '0'], ['17', '25.01', '18.01', '16.14', 'AM', '18', '3', '8', 'BA', '8', '9', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['18', '26.01', '18.01', '09:36', 'AM', '1', '17', '9', 'BA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['19', '26.01', '18.01', '13.4', 'BA', '3', '9', '14', 'AM', '10', '8', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['20', '26.01', '19.01', '14.3', 'BA', '1', '14', '11', 'AM', '7', '10', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['21', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'AM', '9', '12', '14', 'BA', '4', '10', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['22', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'BA', '4', '7', '16', 'AM', '6', '7', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['23', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'AM', '7', '3', '14', 'BA', '5', '11', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['24', '30.01', '22.01', '13.01', 'BA', '6', '7', '15', 'AM', '7', '9', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['25', '30.01', '22.01', '13.01', 'AM', '18', '7', '7', 'BA', '5', '14', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['26', '30.01', '22.01', '13.39', 'AM', '3', '9', '22', 'BA', '3', '3', '22', '0', '0', '0'], ['27', '30.01', '22.01', '13.39', 'BA', '5', '11', '16', 'AM', '5', '17', '7', '0', '0', '0'], ['28', '31.01', '23.01', '15.46', 'BA', '7', '6', '11', 'AM', '7', '10', '5', '0', '0', '0'], ['29', '31.01', '23.01', '15.46', 'BA', '10', '7', '9', 'AM', '7', '10', '5', '0', '0', '0'], ['30', '31.01', '23.01', '0', 'AM', '11', '6', '9', 'BA', '2', '7', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['31', '31.01', '23.01', '0', 'BA', '7', '11', '13', 'AM', '10', '3', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['32', '2.01', '24.01', '13.08', 'BA', '7', '11', '10', 'AM', '8', '11', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['33', '2.01', '24.01', '13.08', 'AM', '10', '6', '9', 'BA', '9', '13', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['34', '2.01', '25.01', '14.29', 'AM', '6', '7', '17', 'BA', '6', '10', '16', '0', '0', '0'], ['35', '2.01', '25.01', '14.29', 'BA', '3', '10', '16', 'AM', '2', '6', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['36', '2.01', '25.01', '15.2', 'BA', '9', '11', '10', 'AM', '7', '7', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['37', '2.01', '25.01', '15.2', 'AM', '10', '7', '14', 'BA', '6', '7', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['38', '2.01', '25.01', '16.26', 'AM', '7', '13', '8', 'BA', '8', '6', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['39', '2.01', '25.01', '16.26', 'BA', '4', '12', '14', 'AM', '9', '12', '6', '0', '0', '0'], ['40', '2.01', '25.01', '17.1', 'BA', '5', '8', '15', 'AM', '13', '9', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['41', '2.01', '25.01', '17.1', 'AM', '9', '12', '9', 'BA', '17', '5', '10', '0', '0', '0']]
```

function returning resultsTable:

```
def getResults(self, csvInput):
    with open (csvInput, 'rt') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        resultsTable = []
        for row in reader:
            resultsTable.append(row) 
        return resultsTable
```

listPrefInd_a:

```
[0.4230769230769231, -0.3793103448275862, -0.03125, -0.0625, -0.0625, -0.72, -0.8214285714285714, -0.08333333333333333, 0.041666666666666664, -0.3793103448275862, 0.11538461538461539, 0.06060606060606061, -0.43333333333333335, -0.20588235294117646, -0.2222222222222222, -0.6333333333333333, 0.3448275862068966, 0, -0.4230769230769231, -0.38461538461538464, -0.14285714285714285, -0.4444444444444444, -0.2916666666666667, -0.32142857142857145, 0.34375, -0.5588235294117647, -0.34375, -0.16666666666666666, 0.038461538461538464, 0.07692307692307693, -0.1935483870967742, -0.10714285714285714, 0.04, -0.36666666666666664, -0.4482758620689655, -0.03333333333333333, -0.12903225806451613, -0.03571428571428571, -0.3333333333333333, -0.35714285714285715, 0.0]
```

listPrefInd_b:

```
[-0.06666666666666667, -0.36666666666666664, -0.09090909090909091, -0.23333333333333334, -0.1, -0.20689655172413793, 0.10714285714285714, -0.5925925925925926, -0.16666666666666666, -0.1935483870967742, -0.2571428571428571, -0.25, -0.7666666666666667, -0.43333333333333335, -0.39285714285714285, -0.5666666666666667, -0.13793103448275862, 0, -0.034482758620689655, -0.25, -0.3076923076923077, -0.20833333333333334, -0.27586206896551724, -0.11538461538461539, -0.1724137931034483, -0.6785714285714286, -0.06896551724137931, 0.09090909090909091, 0.09090909090909091, -0.5925925925925926, -0.041666666666666664, -0.06896551724137931, -0.08823529411764706, -0.3125, -0.6153846153846154, -0.27586206896551724, -0.3870967741935484, -0.15384615384615385, 0.1111111111111111, 0.09375, 0.21875]
```

listPerfInd:

```
[0.1782051282051282, -0.3729885057471264, -0.061079545454545456, -0.14791666666666667, -0.08125, -0.46344827586206894, -0.35714285714285715, -0.33796296296296297, -0.0625, -0.28642936596218016, -0.07087912087912086, -0.0946969696969697, -0.6000000000000001, -0.3196078431372549, -0.30753968253968256, -0.6, 0.10344827586206898, 0, -0.22877984084880637, -0.3173076923076923, -0.22527472527472528, -0.3263888888888889, -0.28376436781609193, -0.2184065934065934, 0.08566810344827586, -0.6186974789915967, -0.20635775862068967, -0.03787878787878787, 0.06468531468531469, -0.25783475783475784, -0.11760752688172042, -0.08805418719211822, -0.024117647058823532, -0.33958333333333335, -0.5318302387267905, -0.15459770114942528, -0.25806451612903225, -0.09478021978021978, -0.1111111111111111, -0.13169642857142858, 0.109375]
```

The columns formed by entries at row[12], row[13], row[14] of resultsTable originally contain only zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code logic is a bit off.  It modified the header row, then the line after the header row was printed, then it modified the header row again due to the while, but printed the next unmodified line, etc.; so it only looked like the table wasn't modified.  Once count was high enough the while wouldn't be entered anymore, but row would start advancing.  The end result was only the header row was modified over and over again.  Change `print(row[12])` to `print(row)` and you'll see what I mean.

Here's a corrected version with comments:

```
count = 0
for row in resultsTable[1:]: # skip header row via slicing.
    # while not needed, and prevented row from advancing
    print(count)
    row[12] = listPrefInd_a[count]
    row[13] = listPrefInd_b[count]
    row[14] = listPerfInd[count]
    print(row[12])                #debugging print
    count+=1                      #advance to next row
    print(resultsTable[count])    #this gives the correct offset skipping header.
```

The above is confusing.  Here's an advanced version and demo.  `zip()` returns an iterator that returns the first elements from each of its iterable parameters, then the 2nd elements, etc.; then `row[12:]` (element 12 to the end) is replaced with the three values in replacements:

```
def resultsUpdate(resultsTable, listPrefInd_a, listPrefInd_b, listPerfInd):
    for row,replacements in zip(resultsTable[1:],zip(listPrefInd_a,listPrefInd_b,listPerfInd)):
        row[12:] = replacements

resultsTable = [['nummer', 'datum', 'larvae', 'zeit', 'gruppe1', 'cs_a', 'med_a', 'neut_a', 'gruppe2', 'cs_b', 'med_b', 'neut_b', 'prefInd_a', 'prefInd_b', 'perfInd'], ['1', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '15', '7', '4', 'BA', '11', '6', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '6', '17', 'BA', '4', '11', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['3', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '9', '13', '10', 'AM', '8', '14', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['4', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '10', '10', '12', 'BA', '7', '9', '14', '0', '0', '0'], ['5', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '10', '10', '12', 'AM', '10', '7', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['6', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '1', '5', '19', 'BA', '7', '9', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['7', '23.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '2', '1', '25', 'AM', '14', '3', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['8', '23.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '10', '8', 'BA', '2', '7', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['9', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'BA', '8', '9', '7', 'AM', '6', '8', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['10', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'AM', '5', '8', '16', 'BA', '10', '5', '16', '0', '0', '0'], ['11', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'BA', '9', '11', '6', 'AM', '7', '12', '16', '0', '0', '0'], ['12', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'AM', '14', '7', '12', 'BA', '8', '5', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['13', '25.01', '17.01', '13.23', 'BA', '4', '9', '17', 'AM', '2', '3', '25', '0', '0', '0'], ['14', '25.01', '17.01', '13.46', 'AM', '8', '11', '15', 'BA', '6', '5', '19', '0', '0', '0'], ['15', '25.01', '18.01', '14.49', 'BA', '6', '9', '12', 'AM', '6', '5', '17', '0', '0', '0'], ['16', '25.01', '18.01', '15.24', 'AM', '2', '7', '21', 'BA', '3', '7', '20', '0', '0', '0'], ['17', '25.01', '18.01', '16.14', 'AM', '18', '3', '8', 'BA', '8', '9', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['18', '26.01', '18.01', '09:36', 'AM', '1', '17', '9', 'BA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['19', '26.01', '18.01', '13.4', 'BA', '3', '9', '14', 'AM', '10', '8', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['20', '26.01', '19.01', '14.3', 'BA', '1', '14', '11', 'AM', '7', '10', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['21', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'AM', '9', '12', '14', 'BA', '4', '10', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['22', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'BA', '4', '7', '16', 'AM', '6', '7', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['23', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'AM', '7', '3', '14', 'BA', '5', '11', '13', '0', '0', '0'], ['24', '30.01', '22.01', '13.01', 'BA', '6', '7', '15', 'AM', '7', '9', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['25', '30.01', '22.01', '13.01', 'AM', '18', '7', '7', 'BA', '5', '14', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['26', '30.01', '22.01', '13.39', 'AM', '3', '9', '22', 'BA', '3', '3', '22', '0', '0', '0'], ['27', '30.01', '22.01', '13.39', 'BA', '5', '11', '16', 'AM', '5', '17', '7', '0', '0', '0'], ['28', '31.01', '23.01', '15.46', 'BA', '7', '6', '11', 'AM', '7', '10', '5', '0', '0', '0'], ['29', '31.01', '23.01', '15.46', 'BA', '10', '7', '9', 'AM', '7', '10', '5', '0', '0', '0'], ['30', '31.01', '23.01', '0', 'AM', '11', '6', '9', 'BA', '2', '7', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['31', '31.01', '23.01', '0', 'BA', '7', '11', '13', 'AM', '10', '3', '11', '0', '0', '0'], ['32', '2.01', '24.01', '13.08', 'BA', '7', '11', '10', 'AM', '8', '11', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['33', '2.01', '24.01', '13.08', 'AM', '10', '6', '9', 'BA', '9', '13', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['34', '2.01', '25.01', '14.29', 'AM', '6', '7', '17', 'BA', '6', '10', '16', '0', '0', '0'], ['35', '2.01', '25.01', '14.29', 'BA', '3', '10', '16', 'AM', '2', '6', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['36', '2.01', '25.01', '15.2', 'BA', '9', '11', '10', 'AM', '7', '7', '15', '0', '0', '0'], ['37', '2.01', '25.01', '15.2', 'AM', '10', '7', '14', 'BA', '6', '7', '18', '0', '0', '0'], ['38', '2.01', '25.01', '16.26', 'AM', '7', '13', '8', 'BA', '8', '6', '12', '0', '0', '0'], ['39', '2.01', '25.01', '16.26', 'BA', '4', '12', '14', 'AM', '9', '12', '6', '0', '0', '0'], ['40', '2.01', '25.01', '17.1', 'BA', '5', '8', '15', 'AM', '13', '9', '10', '0', '0', '0'], ['41', '2.01', '25.01', '17.1', 'AM', '9', '12', '9', 'BA', '17', '5', '10', '0', '0', '0']]

listPrefInd_a = [0.4230769230769231, -0.3793103448275862, -0.03125, -0.0625, -0.0625, -0.72, -0.8214285714285714, -0.08333333333333333, 0.041666666666666664, -0.3793103448275862, 0.11538461538461539, 0.06060606060606061, -0.43333333333333335, -0.20588235294117646, -0.2222222222222222, -0.6333333333333333, 0.3448275862068966, 0, -0.4230769230769231, -0.38461538461538464, -0.14285714285714285, -0.4444444444444444, -0.2916666666666667, -0.32142857142857145, 0.34375, -0.5588235294117647, -0.34375, -0.16666666666666666, 0.038461538461538464, 0.07692307692307693, -0.1935483870967742, -0.10714285714285714, 0.04, -0.36666666666666664, -0.4482758620689655, -0.03333333333333333, -0.12903225806451613, -0.03571428571428571, -0.3333333333333333, -0.35714285714285715, 0.0]
listPrefInd_b = [-0.06666666666666667, -0.36666666666666664, -0.09090909090909091, -0.23333333333333334, -0.1, -0.20689655172413793, 0.10714285714285714, -0.5925925925925926, -0.16666666666666666, -0.1935483870967742, -0.2571428571428571, -0.25, -0.7666666666666667, -0.43333333333333335, -0.39285714285714285, -0.5666666666666667, -0.13793103448275862, 0, -0.034482758620689655, -0.25, -0.3076923076923077, -0.20833333333333334, -0.27586206896551724, -0.11538461538461539, -0.1724137931034483, -0.6785714285714286, -0.06896551724137931, 0.09090909090909091, 0.09090909090909091, -0.5925925925925926, -0.041666666666666664, -0.06896551724137931, -0.08823529411764706, -0.3125, -0.6153846153846154, -0.27586206896551724, -0.3870967741935484, -0.15384615384615385, 0.1111111111111111, 0.09375, 0.21875]
listPerfInd = [0.1782051282051282, -0.3729885057471264, -0.061079545454545456, -0.14791666666666667, -0.08125, -0.46344827586206894, -0.35714285714285715, -0.33796296296296297, -0.0625, -0.28642936596218016, -0.07087912087912086, -0.0946969696969697, -0.6000000000000001, -0.3196078431372549, -0.30753968253968256, -0.6, 0.10344827586206898, 0, -0.22877984084880637, -0.3173076923076923, -0.22527472527472528, -0.3263888888888889, -0.28376436781609193, -0.2184065934065934, 0.08566810344827586, -0.6186974789915967, -0.20635775862068967, -0.03787878787878787, 0.06468531468531469, -0.25783475783475784, -0.11760752688172042, -0.08805418719211822, -0.024117647058823532, -0.33958333333333335, -0.5318302387267905, -0.15459770114942528, -0.25806451612903225, -0.09478021978021978, -0.1111111111111111, -0.13169642857142858, 0.109375]

resultsUpdate(resultsTable, listPrefInd_a, listPrefInd_b, listPerfInd)

for row in resultsTable:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
['nummer', 'datum', 'larvae', 'zeit', 'gruppe1', 'cs_a', 'med_a', 'neut_a', 'gruppe2', 'cs_b', 'med_b', 'neut_b', 'prefInd_a', 'prefInd_b', 'perfInd']
['1', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '15', '7', '4', 'BA', '11', '6', '13', 0.4230769230769231, -0.06666666666666667, 0.1782051282051282]
['2', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '6', '17', 'BA', '4', '11', '15', -0.3793103448275862, -0.36666666666666664, -0.3729885057471264]
['3', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '9', '13', '10', 'AM', '8', '14', '11', -0.03125, -0.09090909090909091, -0.061079545454545456]
['4', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '10', '10', '12', 'BA', '7', '9', '14', -0.0625, -0.23333333333333334, -0.14791666666666667]
['5', '19.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '10', '10', '12', 'AM', '10', '7', '13', -0.0625, -0.1, -0.08125]
['6', '19.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '1', '5', '19', 'BA', '7', '9', '13', -0.72, -0.20689655172413793, -0.46344827586206894]
['7', '23.01', '0', '0', 'BA', '2', '1', '25', 'AM', '14', '3', '11', -0.8214285714285714, 0.10714285714285714, -0.35714285714285715]
['8', '23.01', '0', '0', 'AM', '6', '10', '8', 'BA', '2', '7', '18', -0.08333333333333333, -0.5925925925925926, -0.33796296296296297]
['9', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'BA', '8', '9', '7', 'AM', '6', '8', '10', 0.041666666666666664, -0.16666666666666666, -0.0625]
['10', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'AM', '5', '8', '16', 'BA', '10', '5', '16', -0.3793103448275862, -0.1935483870967742, -0.28642936596218016]
['11', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'BA', '9', '11', '6', 'AM', '7', '12', '16', 0.11538461538461539, -0.2571428571428571, -0.07087912087912086]
['12', '24.01', '17.01', '0', 'AM', '14', '7', '12', 'BA', '8', '5', '15', 0.06060606060606061, -0.25, -0.0946969696969697]
['13', '25.01', '17.01', '13.23', 'BA', '4', '9', '17', 'AM', '2', '3', '25', -0.43333333333333335, -0.7666666666666667, -0.6000000000000001]
['14', '25.01', '17.01', '13.46', 'AM', '8', '11', '15', 'BA', '6', '5', '19', -0.20588235294117646, -0.43333333333333335, -0.3196078431372549]
['15', '25.01', '18.01', '14.49', 'BA', '6', '9', '12', 'AM', '6', '5', '17', -0.2222222222222222, -0.39285714285714285, -0.30753968253968256]
['16', '25.01', '18.01', '15.24', 'AM', '2', '7', '21', 'BA', '3', '7', '20', -0.6333333333333333, -0.5666666666666667, -0.6]
['17', '25.01', '18.01', '16.14', 'AM', '18', '3', '8', 'BA', '8', '9', '12', 0.3448275862068966, -0.13793103448275862, 0.10344827586206898]
['18', '26.01', '18.01', '09:36', 'AM', '1', '17', '9', 'BA', '0', '0', '0', 0, 0, 0]
['19', '26.01', '18.01', '13.4', 'BA', '3', '9', '14', 'AM', '10', '8', '11', -0.4230769230769231, -0.034482758620689655, -0.22877984084880637]
['20', '26.01', '19.01', '14.3', 'BA', '1', '14', '11', 'AM', '7', '10', '15', -0.38461538461538464, -0.25, -0.3173076923076923]
['21', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'AM', '9', '12', '14', 'BA', '4', '10', '12', -0.14285714285714285, -0.3076923076923077, -0.22527472527472528]
['22', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'BA', '4', '7', '16', 'AM', '6', '7', '11', -0.4444444444444444, -0.20833333333333334, -0.3263888888888889]
['23', '26.01', '19.01', '0', 'AM', '7', '3', '14', 'BA', '5', '11', '13', -0.2916666666666667, -0.27586206896551724, -0.28376436781609193]
['24', '30.01', '22.01', '13.01', 'BA', '6', '7', '15', 'AM', '7', '9', '10', -0.32142857142857145, -0.11538461538461539, -0.2184065934065934]
['25', '30.01', '22.01', '13.01', 'AM', '18', '7', '7', 'BA', '5', '14', '10', 0.34375, -0.1724137931034483, 0.08566810344827586]
['26', '30.01', '22.01', '13.39', 'AM', '3', '9', '22', 'BA', '3', '3', '22', -0.5588235294117647, -0.6785714285714286, -0.6186974789915967]
['27', '30.01', '22.01', '13.39', 'BA', '5', '11', '16', 'AM', '5', '17', '7', -0.34375, -0.06896551724137931, -0.20635775862068967]
['28', '31.01', '23.01', '15.46', 'BA', '7', '6', '11', 'AM', '7', '10', '5', -0.16666666666666666, 0.09090909090909091, -0.03787878787878787]
['29', '31.01', '23.01', '15.46', 'BA', '10', '7', '9', 'AM', '7', '10', '5', 0.038461538461538464, 0.09090909090909091, 0.06468531468531469]
['30', '31.01', '23.01', '0', 'AM', '11', '6', '9', 'BA', '2', '7', '18', 0.07692307692307693, -0.5925925925925926, -0.25783475783475784]
['31', '31.01', '23.01', '0', 'BA', '7', '11', '13', 'AM', '10', '3', '11', -0.1935483870967742, -0.041666666666666664, -0.11760752688172042]
['32', '2.01', '24.01', '13.08', 'BA', '7', '11', '10', 'AM', '8', '11', '10', -0.10714285714285714, -0.06896551724137931, -0.08805418719211822]
['33', '2.01', '24.01', '13.08', 'AM', '10', '6', '9', 'BA', '9', '13', '12', 0.04, -0.08823529411764706, -0.024117647058823532]
['34', '2.01', '25.01', '14.29', 'AM', '6', '7', '17', 'BA', '6', '10', '16', -0.36666666666666664, -0.3125, -0.33958333333333335]
['35', '2.01', '25.01', '14.29', 'BA', '3', '10', '16', 'AM', '2', '6', '18', -0.4482758620689655, -0.6153846153846154, -0.5318302387267905]
['36', '2.01', '25.01', '15.2', 'BA', '9', '11', '10', 'AM', '7', '7', '15', -0.03333333333333333, -0.27586206896551724, -0.15459770114942528]
['37', '2.01', '25.01', '15.2', 'AM', '10', '7', '14', 'BA', '6', '7', '18', -0.12903225806451613, -0.3870967741935484, -0.25806451612903225]
['38', '2.01', '25.01', '16.26', 'AM', '7', '13', '8', 'BA', '8', '6', '12', -0.03571428571428571, -0.15384615384615385, -0.09478021978021978]
['39', '2.01', '25.01', '16.26', 'BA', '4', '12', '14', 'AM', '9', '12', '6', -0.3333333333333333, 0.1111111111111111, -0.1111111111111111]
['40', '2.01', '25.01', '17.1', 'BA', '5', '8', '15', 'AM', '13', '9', '10', -0.35714285714285715, 0.09375, -0.13169642857142858]
['41', '2.01', '25.01', '17.1', 'AM', '9', '12', '9', 'BA', '17', '5', '10', 0.0, 0.21875, 0.109375]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I used the first version of your solution and am now looking at the second.

Comment: You're welcome.  If an answer useful to you, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer with the controls to the left.

Answer (score -1):

you are using csv.reader which reads from csv files and gives you the data in the form of variables. You're updating the variables, but of course the variables doesn't update the file.

You need to use csv.writer to update the file.

Comment: OP isn't updating the file, just the table in memory.